# JSON - Bluemix application in Eclipse Mars

Tags: json, eclipse, ibm-cloud

I imported my Bluemix application into Eclipse. When I open it, I get a JSON error. What do I have to do to not get this error? Is there a tutorial for this?
[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F2cT.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots. Can you also provide what packages are being imported?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include some actual code / error messages. I am not going to read /. try and debug from screenshots. Voting to close for lack of details.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a JSON error actually. Most likely the IDE is not able to find the *JSONObject* class during the project build. If you leave the mouse pointer on the JSONObject class name you will read the error (actually I suggest you to enable the problems view to see all the errors: Windows->Show View->Problems).

You need to make the class *JSONObject* available to *DemoServlet* fixing the project java build path.

I guess you are using [personality-insights-java](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/personality-insights-java). I've just tried to import it in a blank Eclipse project and I managed to build it correctly.

1. I am assuming that you have a local instance of Liberty server on which you want to run the application. If not see [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/getstarted/). Go to step 2 only when you have a local working application server in Eclipse
2. double check that the project Java Build Path (right click on the project->Properties->Java Build Path) contains Liberty libraries (Libraries->Add Library->Server Runtime->WebSphere Application Server Liberty)
3. If the auto-build is not enabled, manually clean and build the project (Project->Clean)